# Auto-mount all USB-devices at same USB socket to same mountpoint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, debian, automount

- I have a small computer with 2 USB sockets : A and B.
- I want **any external USB disk**, attached to **socket A** - to be mounted as "**deviceA**"
- I want **any external USB disk**, attached to **socket B** - to be mounted as "**deviceB**"

**Expecially**: 
Any amount of different disks may be attached to socket A. They all shall be mounted as "devicesA". 
Because of this case I can not use UUIDs of disks and have to identify the sockets.

I am using udev rules to automount the disks.
How would I implement that?

**Edit:** Adding

```
$ udevadm info -a -n /dev/sda1
```

```
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1':
    KERNEL=="sda1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="1953521072"
    ATTR{stat}=="   51373   677289  5403472   637670        0        0        0        0        0   453380   637110"
    ATTR{partition}=="1"
    ATTR{start}=="2048"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda':
    KERNELS=="sda"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="block"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{ro}=="0"
    ATTRS{size}=="1953525168"
    ATTRS{stat}=="   51459   677289  5404160   637880        0        0        0        0        0   453600   637320"
    ATTRS{range}=="16"
    ATTRS{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTRS{events}==""
    ATTRS{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTRS{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
    ATTRS{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTRS{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="0"
    ATTRS{capability}=="50"
    ATTRS{events_async}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="1:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{rev}=="0001"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="7"
    ATTRS{model}=="External USB 3.0"
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0xc9c1"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0xc9c1"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{max_sectors}=="240"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x9c"
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="TOSHIBA "
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host1/target1:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target1:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host1':
    KERNELS=="host1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="50"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0480"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0001"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="2013101772997"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="409012"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="TOSHIBA"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="a006"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="External USB 3.0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0424"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="  2mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="3"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="62"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9512"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="  0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0306"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="bcm2708_usb"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="25"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.6.11+ dwc_otg_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="DWC OTG Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb':
    KERNELS=="bcm2708_usb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="dwc_otg"
    ATTRS{hnp}=="HstNegScs = 0x0"
    ATTRS{srp}=="SesReqScs = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regvalue}=="invalid offset"
    ATTRS{hsic_connect}=="HSIC Connect = 0x1"
    ATTRS{guid}=="GUID = 0x2708a000"
    ATTRS{mode}=="Mode = 0x1"
    ATTRS{srpcapable}=="SRPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regdump}=="Register Dump"
    ATTRS{gpvndctl}=="GPVNDCTL = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{ggpio}=="GGPIO = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{hprt0}=="HPRT0 = 0x00001005"
    ATTRS{wr_reg_test}=="Time to write GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 490 msecs (49 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{hcd_frrem}=="HCD Dump Frame Remaining"
    ATTRS{mode_ch_tim_en}=="Mode Change Ready Timer Enable = 0x0"
    ATTRS{gnptxfsiz}=="GNPTXFSIZ = 0x01000306"
    ATTRS{remote_wakeup}=="Remote Wakeup Sig = 0 Enabled = 0 LPM Remote Wakeup = 0"
    ATTRS{busconnected}=="Bus Connected = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hcddump}=="HCD Dump"
    ATTRS{gotgctl}=="GOTGCTL = 0x001c0001"
    ATTRS{spramdump}=="SPRAM Dump"
    ATTRS{grxfsiz}=="GRXFSIZ = 0x00000306"
    ATTRS{gsnpsid}=="GSNPSID = 0x4f54280a"
    ATTRS{gusbcfg}=="GUSBCFG = 0x00001700"
    ATTRS{hptxfsiz}=="HPTXFSIZ = 0x02000406"
    ATTRS{devspeed}=="Device Speed = 0x0"
    ATTRS{fr_interval}=="Frame Interval = 0x1d4c"
    ATTRS{rem_wakeup_pwrdn}==""
    ATTRS{bussuspend}=="Bus Suspend = 0x0"
    ATTRS{buspower}=="Bus Power = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hnpcapable}=="HNPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{rd_reg_test}=="Time to read GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 1620 msecs (162 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{enumspeed}=="Device Enumeration Speed = 0x1"
    ATTRS{inv_sel_hsic}=="Invert Select HSIC = 0x0"
    ATTRS{regoffset}=="0xffffffff"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: Can you add the `udevadm info -a -n /dev/xxx` for a device plugged into socket A?

Comment: If you compare the same device in B can you see a `KERNELS` line that we can match against?  It depends a bit whether A and B are on the same controller or different ones.